# Connecting to different database versions

Tags: oracle, oracle-pro-c

I maintain a set of applications that use Pro*C to connect to Oracle 10g databases. These applications are generally involved with moving data from one database to another. In each case a connection is made to the source database and a separate connection is made to the target database. For reasons that are out of my control the target databases are to be upgraded to 11g whilst the source databases are not. I have searched the internet unsuccessfully, well I have posed the problem as many different ways as I can think of in google, in order to determine whether connecting to different versions of the database is acceptable .The only, almost relevant, documentation I can find is [this](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28300/app.htm)  Can anyone point me to any other documentation that would allay my clients fears?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official client/ server compatibility matrix for Oracle is My Oracle Support 207303.1 "Client/ Server/ Interoperability Support Between Different Oracle Versions".  That is probably the documentation that your clients would want to see.

The quick version is that if your application were to use, say, the 10.2 Oracle client, you would be able to connect to databases from 9.2.0.4 to 11.2.0.x.  If your application were to use the 9.2 Oracle client, you'd be able to connect to databases from 8.1.7.x to 11.2.0.x.  If you used an earlier version of the Oracle client, you would not be able to connect to an 11.1 or an 11.2 database.